# getting corrupt file while trying to download excel(.xlsx) when sending the file from the server to client

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, excel

> My goal is to send excel (.xlsx) file to the client and download the excel file. Below is my server side code which returns ResponseEntity.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/proccessFile") 
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> processFileAndDownload(@RequestBody String sheetName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
        //some logic applied to the file CollibraOutputTemplateDataAttrName and the file is a saved in a tmp folder
        collibraAutomationScript.processingFiles(sheetName);

        //preparing CollibraOutputTemplateDataAttrName.xlsx for download
            File file=new File("tmp/CollibraOutputTemplateDataAttrName.xlsx");  
            Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());          
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

             ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
             HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
             headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename="+ file.getName());
                        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .headers(headers)
                        .contentLength(file.length())
                        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                        .body(resource);                 

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }
```

> the ajax code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'application/json',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/proccessFile',
    data: nameOfSheet,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
      var data = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
      var link=document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
      link.download='CollibraOutputTemplateDataAttrName.xlsx'
      link.click();
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // process error
    }
  });
```

> The file is downloading but when i try to open it gives that "The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt." I have tried various solutions present on stackoverflow regrading this issue but nothing helped. 
>   In the same code i give type: 'text/plain' and send a text file from server it works perfectly, the text file downloaded is not corrupt. Not understanding where i am going wrong with excel files?

Comment: have you tried to use application/vnd.ms-excel instead of application/octet-stream?

Comment: @EdBangs i just tried to  use application/vnd.ms-excelwrite but no use! same problem still i am getting corrupt file.